# Событие, которое срабатывает при запуске приложения wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в wxwidgets событие, которое срабатывает при открытии приложения? Вот к примеру вижу EVT_CLOSE, а EVT_OPEN? или что-то подобное?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по упоминанию *EVT_CLOSE* под приложением вы имеете ввиду окно (window), а не application.

Если вам нужно обрабатывать событие показа окна, используйте обработчик для события типа wxEVT_SHOW - *[wxShowEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_show_event.html)* , например, так:

```
    Bind(wxEVT_SHOW, [&](wxShowEvent& event)
        { wxMessageBox("Окно показано!"); });
```

Для обработки событий создания окна (только для тех, что создаются методом Create), существует событие типа wxEVT_CREATE - [wxWindowCreateEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window_create_event.html)

Если ваш вопрос про application, то просто поместите свой код в функцию [OnInit/0](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#a99953775a2fd83fa2456e390779afe15).